# Boolean in a numpy sum

Tags: python, numpy

I have a block of code which uses numpy.sum:

```
import numpy as np
n = 1000
ndice = 10
nsix = 3
dice = np.random.random_integers(6,size=(ndice,n))
p = np.sum(np.sum(dice==6,0)>=nsix)/float(n)
print 'probability:', p
```

I'm basically wondering, what this line is doing:

```
p = np.sum(np.sum(dice==6,0)>=nsix)/float(n)
```

Looking up the numpy.sum documentation I can't really see how it's being used: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html

I guess there's two parts.

1 What does this accomplish?

```
np.sum(dice==6,0)
```

2 Does it.. sum a boolean?

Any explanation would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: do you have IPython installed? It's pretty what's going on when you break `dice==6` into its own statement.

Comment: @PaulH This piece of code is just from a site, it's not something I'm gonna run. I just need to understand what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dice` is a `ndice x n` or 10 x 1000 matrix of integer values from 1 to 6. `dice==6` turns that matrix into a matrix of booleans corresponding to True for all the 6s.

`np.sum(dice==6,0)` is the same as `np.sum(dice==6, axis=0)`, meaning the sum is taken along the `ndice` axis, so now you have a 1 x 1000 array. You have n=1000 runs, each run has ndice=10 die. This 1 x 1000 array now represents how many die out of 10 in each run turned up 6s.

`np.sum(dice==6,0)>=nsix` converts that to a boolean 1 x 1000 array, which for each run (here we have 1000 runs) will be true if at least `nsix` number of die turn up 6s. Taking the sum of this 1 x 1000 array then gives you the number of runs where this is true.

Comment: If I understood correctly, does this: `np.sum(dice==6, axis=0)` mean it sums together every ndice where the entry is 6? So say if dice[1, 0] and [2, 0] are 6, and the rest are different, [0] in the new sum array will be 12?

Comment: Oh wait, it sums the bools, so [0] will be 2 in that example?

Comment: yep, exactly, it sums the booleans.

Answer (score 1):

If you cant run the program yourself, I run it for you, and these are the parts of intersts:

```
In [28]: dice
Out[28]: 
array([[2, 2, 2, ..., 5, 1, 1],
       [3, 1, 3, ..., 6, 3, 5],
       [1, 3, 4, ..., 6, 4, 6],
       ..., 
       [1, 4, 6, ..., 1, 1, 4],
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 6, 1, 3],
       [6, 2, 6, ..., 2, 6, 5]])

In [29]: dice==6
Out[29]: 
array([[False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ...,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ...,  True, False,  True],
       ..., 
       [False, False,  True, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ...,  True, False, False],
       [ True, False,  True, ..., False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)

In [30]: np.sum(dice==6,0)
Out[30]: 
array([2, 1, 3, 3, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 4,
       2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 0, 4, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3,
       1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0,
       3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1,
       5, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 0, 2, 5, 1, 1, 0, 3, 3, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 4,
       2, 4, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1,
       1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2,
       1, 1, 3, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2,
       3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 2, 2, 3,
       2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 5, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 4, 4, 2, 2, 0,
       3, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 6, 2, 3,
       0, 4, 2, 2, 4, 1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 2,
       2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4,
       3, 4, 2, 3, 0, 3, 2, 0, 2, 0, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2,
       0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 3, 4, 2, 2, 5, 1, 0, 3, 4, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 3, 2,
       1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 0, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 5, 3,
       1, 3, 1, 1, 0, 3, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1,
       0, 3, 1, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1,
       3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 2, 0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 1, 4, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 0, 2, 1,
       2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 3, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0,
       0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 3, 0, 4, 1,
       0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0,
       0, 0, 4, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 5, 1, 1, 0, 2, 4, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1,
       2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1,
       2, 2, 3, 0, 2, 3, 0, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2,
       0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0,
       6, 3, 3, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2,
       1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 4, 0, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 4, 1,
       3, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3,
       1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 1,
       1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 5, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 3, 0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1,
       2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3,
       2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 0, 4, 2, 4,
       2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3,
       3, 1, 2, 5, 1, 0, 1, 3, 2, 6, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 2, 1, 3, 0, 0, 2, 3,
       2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1,
       2, 3, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 3, 5, 2, 4,
       1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 4, 1, 1, 4, 1, 0, 2, 0,
       2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 0, 3, 1,
       0, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 6, 3, 3, 0, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1,
       2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 5, 0, 2, 3, 1,
       2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 1])


In [40]: np.sum(dice==6,0)>=nsix
Out[40]: 
array([False, False,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False,
       False,  True,  True, False,  True, False, False, False, False,
       False,  True,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False,  True,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False,  True,  True, False, False,  True,
       False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False,
       False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False,  True,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        True, False, False,  True, False, False, False,  True, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,
       False, False,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False,
       False,  True, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,
       False, False,  True, False, False, False,  True,  True, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False,
        True, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False,
       False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True, False,
       False,  True, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False,
        True, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False,  True, False,  True,  True, False, False,  True, False,
       False,  True,  True, False, False, False,  True, False, False,
       False, False, False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False,
        True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,
       False,  True, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,
        True, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        True, False,  True,  True,  True, False,  True, False,  True,
       False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False,
        True,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True, False,
       False,  True, False, False,  True,  True, False, False, False,
       False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False,  True,
       False, False, False, False,  True, False,  True, False, False,
       False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False,  True,  True,
       False,  True, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False,  True,
       False, False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False,  True,
       False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False,
       False,  True, False, False, False,  True,  True, False, False,
       False,  True, False, False, False,  True, False,  True, False,
        True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False,  True, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False,  True,
       False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False,
       False, False, False,  True, False,  True, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,
       False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False,
       False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False,
        True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        True, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False,  True,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,
       False,  True, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False,
        True, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False, False,
       False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False,
       False, False, False,  True,  True, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,
       False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False,  True, False,  True, False, False,
        True, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False,  True, False, False, False, False,  True,  True, False,
        True, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False,
       False, False,  True, False,  True, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False, False,
        True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False,  True, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False,  True, False, False,  True,  True, False,
       False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,
        True,  True, False, False, False,  True, False,  True, False,
       False,  True, False,  True, False, False, False,  True, False,
       False, False,  True, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,
        True, False, False,  True, False, False, False,  True, False,
        True, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False,
        True, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,
       False, False, False,  True, False,  True, False, False, False,
       False, False,  True, False,  True, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False,  True,  True, False,  True, False, False, False,
       False,  True, False,  True,  True, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,
       False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False,
       False,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False,  True, False, False, False,  True, False, False,  True,
       False, False,  True, False,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)

In [32]: np.sum(np.sum(dice==6,0)>=nsix)
Out[32]: 212
```

Hope this clarifies things. So to answer to your question "Does it.. sum a boolean?" - yes it does.

Simple example for sum:

```
In [45]: a = np.array([2,5,6,1])

In [46]: a>3
Out[46]: array([False,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)

In [47]: np.sum(a>3)
Out[47]: 2
```

Comment: so `np.sum(dice==6,0)` sets all 6's to 0. What does the >=nsix part do, though? Only sum the numbers that are 3 or higher?

And thanks, I can't run python stuff on this computer right now.

Comment: @user2875994 No worries. I added the result of `np.sum(dice==6,0)>=nsix`. As you see, you are correct.

Comment: How do you know 212 is the sum of all numbers that are 3 or higher? If you don't, could you test with a smaller array to verify it?

Comment: Its not the sum of all numbers that are 3 or higher. it is the amount of such numbers, not sum of their values. I added simple example.

Comment: If I understood correctly, n is the amount of times you simulate throwing ndice dice. So you try throwing 10 dice 1000 times. Now, my question is the other guy says (if I understood correctly) `np.sum(dice==6,0)` creates an array containing the amount of times you got a 6 in each ndice throws of the dice. That's not what I said above, but it sounds more like what the algorithm is trying to do. Would that be correct?

Comment: Sorry, was not going into what the peace of code is trying to do or achieve. I was concentrating more on an individual instructions. In this case, please check answer of @transcranial. It seems to explain more what the algorithm wants to do, than my answer.

Answer (score 1):

if np.sum receives an array of booleans as its argument, it'll sum each element (count True as 1 and False as 0) and return the outcome.

for instance np.sum([True, True, False]) will output 2 :)

Hope this helps. *(The other answers are correct, but maybe too correct?! (especially since you came up with that question while reading some piece of code online, so I supposed you were looking for a quick intuition))*.